Woocommerce On mobile devices, full size images are loaded on Archive page / Single product
I'm using Woocommerce + Shoptimizer + CommerceKit Gallery + EWWW Image Optimizer + LiteSpeed.
When testing with Lighthouse mobile or desktop, images are loaded in full size, and it says I need to load smaller photos even though smaller photos are available. Gallery on single product page view has the zoom option enabled, showing a lightbox to zoom in the image and show full-sized. Currently not using LQIP, but an inline placeholder image before image loads.
How to fix this issue?
Lighthouse report Woocommerce Product Archive
Lighthouse report Woocommerce Product Single
Update:
The "Largest Contentful Paint element" is also delaying site loading, which is a red diagnostic notification unlike the Properly sized images which is an orange square.
LCP on Single Product
LCP on Archive Products
At the moment the image output on Woocommerce Product Archive / Single Product Gallery / Single Product Gallery Thumbnails looks like this:
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" data-srcset="image.jpg.webp">
  <img width="1920" height="1440" src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="gallery-image lazyload" alt="" data-eio="p" 
  data-src="image.jpg.webp" decoding="async" data-srcset="image.jpg.webp 1920w, image-600x450.jpg.webp 600w, image-1024x768.jpg.webp 1024w, image-480x360.jpg.webp 480w, image-768x576.jpg.webp 768w, image-990x743.jpg.webp 990w, image-441x331.jpg.webp 441w" 
  data-sizes="auto" data-eio-rwidth="1920" data-eio-rheight="1440" />
  <noscript>
    <img width="1920" height="1440" src="image.jpg.webp" class="gallery-image" alt="" 
    srcset="image.jpg.webp 1920w, image-600x450.jpg.webp 600w, image-1024x768.jpg.webp 1024w, image-480x360.jpg.webp 480w, image-768x576.jpg.webp 768w, image-990x743.jpg.webp 990w, image-441x331.jpg.webp 441w" sizes="(max-width: 360px) 147px, (max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px" data-eio="l" />
  </noscript>
</picture>




// And the code for Woocommerce Single Product Gallery - Main Photo (first photo has fetchpriority high, while others don't):

<a class="swiper-slide-imglink" title="click to zoom-in" href="photo.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1920x1440">
  <img width="1920" height="1440" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" class="wp-post-image skip-lazy ewww_webp" alt="" title="photo" data-caption="" fetchpriority="high" decoding="async" 
  srcset="photo.jpg.webp 1920w, photo-600x450.jpg.webp 600w, photo-1024x768.jpg.webp 1024w, photo-480x360.jpg.webp 480w, photo-768x576.jpg.webp 768w, photo-990x743.jpg.webp 990w, photo-441x331.jpg.webp 441w" sizes="(max-width: 360px) 330px, (max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px" 
  data-src-img="photo.jpg" 
  data-src-webp="photo.jpg.webp" data-eio="j" />
  <noscript>
    <img width="1920" height="1440" src="photo.jpg.webp" class="wp-post-image skip-lazy" alt="" title="photo" data-caption="" fetchpriority="high" decoding="async" 
    srcset="photo.jpg.webp 1920w, photo-600x450.jpg.webp 600w, photo-1024x768.jpg.webp 1024w, photo-480x360.jpg.webp 480w, photo-768x576.jpg.webp 768w, photo-990x743.jpg.webp 990w, photo-441x331.jpg.webp 441w" 
    sizes="(max-width: 360px) 330px, (max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px" />
  </noscript>
</a>



// And the code for  Woocommerce Single Product Gallery - Thumbnails

<div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper-container cg-thumb-swiper cg-thumbs-4 cg-thumbs-count-5">
  <ul class="swiper-wrapper flex-control-nav" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
    <li class="swiper-slide " itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" data-variation-id="40475" data-index="0">
      <picture>
        <source type="image/webp" data-srcset="photo.jpg.webp">
        <img width="1920" height="1440" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAWgAQAAAACX6mN0AAAAAnRSTlMAAHaTzTgAAAFnSURBVHja7cGBAAAAAMOg+VPf4ARVAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8AxL6wABZkSIIAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="wp-post-image lazyload" alt="" title="photo" data-caption="" decoding="async" data-eio="p" 
        data-src="photo.jpg.webp" 
        
        data-srcset="photo.jpg.webp 1920w, photo-600x450.jpg.webp 600w, photo-1024x768.jpg.webp 1024w, photo-480x360.jpg.webp 480w, photo-768x576.jpg.webp 768w, photo-990x743.jpg.webp 990w, photo-441x331.jpg.webp 441w" 
        
        data-sizes="auto" 
        data-eio-rwidth="1920" data-eio-rheight="1440" />
        <noscript>
          <img width="1920" height="1440" src="photo.jpg.webp" class="wp-post-image" alt="" title="photo" data-caption="" decoding="async" 
          
          srcset="photo.jpg.webp 1920w, photo-600x450.jpg.webp 600w, photo-1024x768.jpg.webp 1024w, photo-480x360.jpg.webp 480w, photo-768x576.jpg.webp 768w, photo-990x743.jpg.webp 990w, photo-441x331.jpg.webp 441w" 
          
          sizes="(max-width: 360px) 75px, (max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px" 
          
          data-eio="l" />
        </noscript>
      </picture>
    </li>

I tried modifying which image size loads, but when changing that, it's not loading bigger images when testing on bigger screen. So if I change picture > source - data-srcset to a smaller image it doesn't show a bigger one, which breaks everything.
I've seen someone posted this issue on Github but there's no solution for this.

If there is no solution in the Github issue, you probably won't find help here. There are people actively working on this on the Woocommerce side. If you really need to appease the Lighthouse gods, then I suggest you find a new plugin. Or, just don't worry about it for now. Seriously, if the rest of the site is performing, log this for the future. Too many people get hung up on the Lighthouse page speed - while very important - isn't detrimental quite yet to SEO and rankings.

Thank you for your response! I might try to use some other plugin for the gallery (but I think that the CommerceKit Gallery is great just needs that last piece of fine tunning making it perfect - that by modifying the Picture element this could be done) .I'm hope that people have this solved for their customers or their own woo shops and I hope some kind person will want to share their solution for it.
